# Delete key not working at all in GNOME 3

Tags: fedora, keyboard, gnome3

My <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd> key is not working in GNOME environment at all. I cannot delete characters in LibreOffice, Terminal, Gvim or even Firefox address bar. The key itself physically works. I can delete files permanently in Nautilus using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌦ Del</kbd> and it normally works in virtual terminals (as reached by <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd>).

I might have caused it myself when trying to repair the behaviour of <kbd>⌦ Del</kbd> in Nautilus in previous GNOME versions. More precisely, I tried to follow this https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8136/how-can-i-delete-a-file-pressing-only-delete-key-in-gnome-36/ without any luck. Now I can delete files permanently either using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌦ Del</kbd>, or by right mouse click.

The desired behavior is the default and expected one - just erase the character after (or under) cursor and move files to Trash.

I work on Fedora 26, GNOME Shell 3.24.3.